# How do I fetch null from arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON like this

```
    {
        "questions": [{
                "Creator_User_ID": "140110",
                "Advisor_User_ID": null,
                "Question_Video_Title": "media",
                "playing_time": null,
                "Created": "2016-01-20T00:00:00",
                "Modified": "2016-01-20T00:00:00",
                "question_video_playingTime": "0:4",
                "Answer_Video_Title": null,
                "Answer_Video_Link": null,
                "answer_video_playingtime": null,
                "StatusName": "Approved",
                "QuestionID": 182

            },
{
                "Creator_User_ID": "140110",
                "Advisor_User_ID": null,
                "Question_Video_Title": "media",
                "playing_time": null,
                "Created": "2016-01-20T00:00:00",
                "Modified": "2016-01-20T00:00:00",
                "question_video_playingTime": "0:4",
                "Answer_Video_Title": null,
                "Answer_Video_Link": null,
                "answer_video_playingtime": null,
                "StatusName": "Approved",
                "QuestionID": 182

            }

        ]
    }
```

I have added values of lets suppose "Answer_Video_Link" into Arraylist for e.g arraylistAnswerLink so the output will be like[null,null,....so on]
As setting this arraylist in a BaseAdapter,the functionality is want to achieve is:

```
 if(arraylistAnswerLink.get(position).contains(null)){
button.setVisibilty(View.Visible)}
else{
button.setVisibilty(View.Gone)
}
```

This my json parsing code

```
jsonInnerArray = jsonInnerObject.getJSONArray("questions");
             for (int j = 0; j <= jsonInnerArray.length(); j++) {
                    jsonArrayObject = jsonInnerArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    Question_Video_Title = jsonArrayObject.getString("Question_Video_Title");

                    question_video_playingTime = jsonArrayObject.getString("question_video_playingTime");
                    String Designation1 = jsonArrayObject.getString("Designation");

                    full_name = jsonArrayObject.getString("User_name");      Question_Video_Link = jsonArrayObject.getString("Question_Video_Link");


                    Answer_Video_Link = jsonArrayObject.getString("Answer_Video_Link");

                    QuestionID = jsonArrayObject.getString("QuestionID");
                 video_thumbnail=jsonArrayObject.getString("video_thumbnail");   }
```

am having error of array index out of bound while fetching null at a particular position of the list.

**Please check my code**

```
public class UnRepliedFragment_ extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private String mParam1;
    View rootview;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    // ArrayList<Integer> arrayListImage;
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayListVideos;
    File mediaFile, vPath;
    String song_dur_str, st, vst, vst1, orginalName;
    String timestamp, advisorID, token;
    int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1000;
    ProgressDialog dlg;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListName, videoName, singleVideoName, questionLink, arrquestion_video_playingTime, answerLinkEmpty;
    String FirstName, durationofVideo, User_name, Question_Video_Title, Question_Video_Link, shorted, cmpsort, question_video_playingTime, path, QuestionID;
    int advisor, pos;
    private List<Modals> feedsList;
    Uri mediaPath;
    PutObjectRequest por;
    String url = "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/talentedge1";
    private static AmazonS3Client sS3Client;
    Uri fileUri;
    static Object Answer_Video_Link;
    ArrayList<Object> answerLink;
    Object item;
    JSONObject jsonObject,innerObject;
    JSONArray innerArray;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unreplied, container, false);


        dlg = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        token = preferences.getString(AppConstant.TOKEN, "");
        advisorID = preferences.getString(AppConstant.USERID, "");
        arrayListVideos = new ArrayList<>();
        feedsList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayListName = new ArrayList<>();
        videoName = new ArrayList<>();

        questionLink = new ArrayList<>();
        arrquestion_video_playingTime = new ArrayList<>();
        answerLink = new ArrayList<>();
        singleVideoName = new ArrayList<>();
        /*
        API hit
         */
        new Proadvice().execute();



        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_unreplied);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        return rootview;
    }


    /*
    Adapter class
     */

    class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        ArrayList<String> videoName;
        ArrayList<String> questionLink;
        ArrayList<String> arrquestion_video_playingTime;
        ArrayList<Object> answerLink;


        public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> videoName, ArrayList<String> questionLink, ArrayList<Object> answerLink, ArrayList<String> arrquestion_video_playingTime) {
            this.videoName = videoName;
            this.questionLink = questionLink;
            this.answerLink = answerLink;
            this.arrquestion_video_playingTime = arrquestion_video_playingTime;

        }


        @Override
        public MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.unreplied_list_row, parent, false);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;

        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {



            holder.txt_it_author.setText(arrayListName.get(position));


            holder.textView.setText(arrquestion_video_playingTime.get(position));


            holder.txt_it_Title.setText(videoName.get(position));


            for (Object value : answerLink) {
                if (value != null) {
                    System.out.println("Not Null" + value);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Null" + value);
                }
            }


        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return videoName.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            ImageView imageView;
            TextView textView, txt_it_author, txt_it_Title, share;
            RippleView relativeLayout;
            LinearLayout imageButtonAnswer;
            FrameLayout frameLayout;


            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                relativeLayout = (RippleView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relative_video_it);
                relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
                imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_it_Video);
                textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_it_duration);
                txt_it_author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_it_author);
                txt_it_Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_it_Title);
                imageButtonAnswer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_answers);

                frameLayout = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relative_play_img);
                imageButtonAnswer.setOnClickListener(this);



            }


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getLayoutPosition();
                int id = v.getId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.relative_play_img:
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Video_ViewAct.class);
                        i.putExtra("position", "" + position);
                        i.putExtra("Question_Video_Link", questionLink.get(position));
                        // i.putExtra("Answer_Video_Link", answerLink.get(position));

                        startActivity(i);
                        break;






                }
            }
        }
    }



    class Proadvice extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            return doInLoginProadvice();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dlg.setMessage("Loading.....");
            dlg.setCancelable(false);
            dlg.show();


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dlg.dismiss();
            if (result.contains("true")) {
                updateUIProadvice(result);


            } 
        }
    }

    private void updateUIProadvice(String result) {


        try {


            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            String message = jsonObject.getString("message");

             innerObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Object");

            innerArray = innerObject.getJSONArray("details");
            //    Log.e("arr", " " + arr);
            for (int i = 0; i <= innerArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = innerArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String advisorID = obj.getString("AdvisorID");

                FirstName = obj.getString("FirstName");

                String LastName = obj.getString("LastName");

                String Email = obj.getString("Email");

                String Password = obj.getString("Password");

                String Designation = obj.getString("Designation");

                String Company = obj.getString("Company");

                String Location = obj.getString("Location");

                String Description = obj.getString("Description");

                String Profile_Pic_Small = obj.getString("Profile_Pic_Small");

                String Profile_Pic_Original = obj.getString("Profile_Pic_Original");

                String No_Questions = obj.getString("No_Questions");

                String No_Answers = obj.getString("No_Answers");

                String No_Up_Votes = obj.getString("No_Up_Votes");

                String No_Followers = obj.getString("No_Followers");

                String IsActive = obj.getString("IsActive");

                String Created = obj.getString("Created");

                String Modified = obj.getString("Modified");




                JSONArray arr1 = innerObject.getJSONArray("questions");



                for (int j = 0; j <= arr1.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject obj1 = arr1.getJSONObject(j);

                    Question_Video_Title = obj1.getString("Question_Video_Title");



                    question_video_playingTime = obj1.getString("question_video_playingTime");
                    String Designation1 = obj1.getString("Designation");


                    User_name = obj1.getString("User_name");


                    Question_Video_Link = obj1.getString("Question_Video_Link");

                    shorted = Question_Video_Title.replace("=", " ");
                    cmpsort = shorted.replace("-", " ");
                    Answer_Video_Link = obj1.get("Answer_Video_Link");

                    QuestionID = obj1.getString("QuestionID");

                    videoName.add((cmpsort));
                    questionLink.add(Question_Video_Link);

                    answerLink.add(Answer_Video_Link);


                    arrayListName.add(User_name);
                    arrquestion_video_playingTime.add(question_video_playingTime);


                    mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(videoName, questionLink, answerLink, arrquestion_video_playingTime);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                }
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String doInLoginProadvice() {

        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(AppConstant.getAdvivisorDetail);
        httppost.addHeader("APIKEY", "123ABC890567");
        httppost.addHeader("Token", token);
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AdvisorID", advisorID));
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();


            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {


                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);

            } else {

                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;

            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            responseString = e.toString();

        }

        return responseString;

    }



}
```

Comment: did you try with arraylistAnswerLink.contains(null) on if condition ?

Comment: Yes I do,but it didn't worked

Comment: post some code of parsing and how did you store the data in array List so after that we identified that what is the problem

Comment: Please check  i have added my json parsing code
and this the data that am saving in arraylist
i.e
if(Answer_Video_Link!=null){
arraylist.add(Answer_Video_Link);
}

[null,  mb lbljckckcclv, null, testtttt, img, three check, check  one, naming, third]

Comment: Answer_Video_Link which type of data String ? . if yes then change it to Object

Comment: Yes it is of string,  I have tried that but getting index out of bound

Comment: did you Change String to an Object ?

Comment: I did this : for (Object item : answerLink) {
                if (item.equals(null)) {
                    Log.e("item",""+item);
                }

Comment: Actually i want to display arraylist data into Listview.

Comment: what i am trying to Say is that create the arrayList Object and then add all the object into that . then print the arrayList Reference . Check my Updated Code .

Comment: Please check i have added my code into it.

Comment: i have updated my Code . Just add this parameter  on your code and Run .i have tried with main method . So Just deploy Same Application on your Environment . it will work for Sure .

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Simple Way to  `Parse JSON array` and easily get `Null` as well as a value pair . Important Thing Do not use variable name as a capital letter it must be start with lower case.
please find programme and you can modify it according to Your Requirement

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class UnRepliedFragment_ {
//Define this as a global varraible
static Object Advisor_User_ID;
static Object Creator_User_ID;
static Object Question_Video_Title;
static Object playing_time;
static Object Created;
static Object Modified;
static Object question_video_playingTime;
static Object Answer_Video_Title;
static Object Answer_Video_Link;
static Object answer_video_playingtime;
static Object StatusName;
static Object QuestionID;
static ArrayList al;



    public void onBindViewHolder() {

        for (Object value : al) {
            if (value != null) {
                System.out.println("Not Null" + value);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Null" + value);
            }
        }

    }




private void updateUIProadvice(String result) {
     //Since i have an limited JSON so Accroding to that i did  parsing . Dont try with getString just try with Get();//method

  try {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(result);
    org.json.simple.JSONArray lang = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) jsonObject.get("questions");
    for (int i = 0; i < lang.size(); i++) {
    }
    Iterator i = lang.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        org.json.simple.JSONObject innerObj = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) i.next();

        Creator_User_ID = innerObj.get("Creator_User_ID").toString();
        Advisor_User_ID = innerObj.get("Advisor_User_ID");
        Question_Video_Title = innerObj.get("Question_Video_Title");
        playing_time = innerObj.get("playing_time");
        Created = innerObj.get("Created");
        Modified = innerObj.get("Modified");
        question_video_playingTime = innerObj.get("question_video_playingTime");
        Answer_Video_Title = innerObj.get("Answer_Video_Title");
        question_video_playingTime = innerObj.get("question_video_playingTime");
        Answer_Video_Title = innerObj.get("Answer_Video_Title");
        Answer_Video_Link = innerObj.get("Answer_Video_Link");
        answer_video_playingtime = innerObj.get("answer_video_playingtime");
        StatusName = innerObj.get("StatusName");
        QuestionID = innerObj.get("QuestionID");

        // Storing data into arrayList
        al = new ArrayList();
        al.add(Creator_User_ID);
        al.add(Advisor_User_ID);
        al.add(Question_Video_Title);
        al.add(playing_time);
        al.add(Created);
        al.add(Modified);
        al.add(question_video_playingTime);
        al.add(Answer_Video_Link);
        al.add(Answer_Video_Title);
        al.add(answer_video_playingtime);
        al.add(QuestionID);
        al.add(StatusName);

        // First Way to get element one by one 
    for (Object value : al) {
            if (value != null) {
                System.out.println("Not Null:" + value);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Null:" + value);
            }
        }


          //or  Second Way 

    Object valuenext=al.get(0); // Get First Index Value
    System.out.println(valuenext);


    }

} catch (ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
as you have added data in arraylist,how will i get the items one by one from it?

Remember i need to fetch only the null value

thanks in advance

Comment: i have Edited the blog please there are two way Either Using for Loop or Using arraylist.get(3); where 3 in index . Happy to help

Comment: I have implemented the same logic i.e First Way to get element one by one ,as am setting this array list on list view,what i want is to fetch data one by one and check at which position my data is null,so that i can implement my logic of showing button visibility at a particular position

As data is dynamic so i don't have idea at which position data will be null

Comment: once again i have Edited the Blog and Check if it is null then print else get the value form arrayList . Check updated blog . happy to help

Comment: it is always going in if condition!

Comment: may be you did Some mistake just copy full source Code on separate java class and Run . because here it works Fine

Comment: Ok, is it ok if will share my code with you,so that you can check where i am wrong?

Comment: Thanks alot for your help I have solved this issue using Hash maps

Comment: @Shalvi .Great best of luck . But for big Application for searching operation ArrayList is the best option . any ways go ahead with HashMap

Comment: Yeah,I used arraylist only... what I did is add all the haspmap into arraylist later on..